# How to answer customer's new feature request after project release

Tags: project

we have done a project, and we have finished the project and released, but after the release, the customer keep asking us to add new features, what should we do? how to handle this situation. say no to customer?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a business transaction with the customer and not a programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are three considerations.

1) Have they paid for work already done? If not, they have an advantage over you. If you think there is risk of them holding payment, I suggest you offer to do a few small change requests in return for them first paying what's due.

2) Do you want to keep them as a customer? Offer them a service contract, or option to pay you a retainer for ongoing work. This could be time and materials, or just a fixed price for  pre-agreed amount of labor.

3) Is there disagreement on what is a change request versus what is a bug fix? If so, spend the time with them explaining the difference, and get their agreement to the principle before arguing over specifics.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy.  More features, more money.

Depending on your contract, of course.  But if the project is all signed off on and the new features are not included in the maintenance contracts, further development is going to have to cost them.